# How to use predicates with xpath in xsd file?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I'm trying to write a `XSD` file for the `xml` file below: (it is actually a `xml` representation of a specific part of an A2L file)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <A2lFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="testXpath.xsd">
    <PROJECT>
        <MODULE>
            <MEASUREMENT>
                <Name>M1</Name>
            </MEASUREMENT>
            <MEASUREMENT>
                <Name>M2</Name>
            </MEASUREMENT>
            <MEASUREMENT>
                <Name>M3</Name>
            </MEASUREMENT>
            <MEASUREMENT>
                <Name>M4</Name>
            </MEASUREMENT>
            <MEASUREMENT>
                <Name>Mn</Name>
            </MEASUREMENT>

            <CHARACTERISTIC>
                <AXIS_DESCR>
                    <InputQuantity>M2</InputQuantity>
                </AXIS_DESCR>
            </CHARACTERISTIC>
            <CHARACTERISTIC>
                <AXIS_DESCR>
                    <InputQuantity>NO_INPUT_QUANTITY</InputQuantity>
                </AXIS_DESCR>
            </CHARACTERISTIC>
            <CHARACTERISTIC>
                <AXIS_DESCR>
                    <InputQuantity>M1</InputQuantity>
                </AXIS_DESCR>
            </CHARACTERISTIC>

        </MODULE>
    </PROJECT>
</A2lFile>
```

One of the constraints I would like to insert using `xpath` is:
If the content of InputQuantity is not equal to "NO_INPUT_QUANTITY" then it should necessary be equal to one of MEASUREMENT names.

The `XPath` expression I used to get the list of "InputQuantity" which content is different from "NO_INPUT_QUANTITY" is:

```
/A2lFile/PROJECT/MODULE/CHARACTERISTIC/AXIS_DESCR/InputQuantity[. !="NO_INPUT_QUANTITY"].
```

This expression is valid and it returns "M2" and "M1". But when I put it in my `xsd` file, the `xsd` validator doesn't accept it and returns this kind of error:

```
The value 'PROJECT/MODULE/CHARACTERISTIC/AXIS_DESCR/InputQuantity[. !="NO_INPUT_QUANTITY"]' 
of attribute 'PROJECT/MODULE/CHARACTERISTIC/AXIS_DESCR/InputQuantity[. !="NO_INPUT_QUANTITY"]' of identity constraint definition 'reference_InputQuantity' 
is not a valid restricted XPath expression.
```

Here is my `xsd` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <!-- file root -->
    <xs:element name="A2lFile" type="A2lFileType">
        <xs:unique name="MEASUREMENT_Name">
            <xs:selector xpath="PROJECT/MODULE/MEASUREMENT/Name"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
        </xs:unique>
        <xs:keyref name="reference_InputQuantity" refer="MEASUREMENT_Name">
            <xs:selector xpath="PROJECT/MODULE/CHARACTERISTIC/AXIS_DESCR/InputQuantity[. !=&quot;NO_INPUT_QUANTITY&quot;]"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="A2lFileType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="PROJECT" type="projectType" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="projectType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MODULE" type="moduleType" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="moduleType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MEASUREMENT" type="measurementType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="CHARACTERISTIC" type="characteristicType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="measurementType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="characteristicType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AXIS_DESCR" type="axis_descType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="axis_descType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="InputQuantity" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML Schema restricts the XPath expressions that can be used to a very simple subset, and filters are not allowed.

I think the most straightforward way to circumvent this is to treat "NO_INPUT_QUANTITY" as a measurement name

```
<MEASUREMENT>
  <Name>NO_INPUT_QUANTITY</Name>
</MEASUREMENT>
```

That way, the filter becomes unnecessary and the XPath expression fulfils XML Schema's constraints.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I can't unfortunately modify the content of the xml file, plus, the NO_INPUT_QUANTITY expression is used only with "InputQuantity" tag. so let's suppose that the xml is fine, is there any way to do this test with <choice> or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expressions that can be used in the `xpath` attribute of `<xs:selector/>` elements is restricted by the [XML Schema specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#c-selector-xpath). This is referred to as the *selector subset of XPath*.

In particular, this means that the XPath expression:

- **cannot contain tests**
- can only select descendant elements